# querying a document in elastic search java

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I want to get 2 fields from a specific field in an elastic search document using java client:

```
public SearchResponse getResponse(String index) {

    SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = SearchSourceBuilder.searchSource();
    SearchResponse response = elasticHandler.prepareSearch()
        .setIndices(index)
        .setQuery(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("provider", "twitter"))
        .setSource(searchSourceBuilder)
        .setFetchSource((new String[] {"originId","name"}), null)
        .setSize(scrollSize).get();

    return response;
}
```

However,the map containing the 2 fields, `originId` and `name` is empty.
Can you please help me?

Comment: Your code should work. Please show the document that you are trying to find and provide the code that you use for getting of field values.